# return the number of a record within the sql table pdo

Tags: sql, pdo

I have a list table: comments

```
comment: id_comment,comment, id_postcommented

comment
---------
comment A
commen  B
comment C
comment D
comment E
comment F
comment G
comment H
comment I
comment J
```

I need to retrieve the number of comment for example

```
`comment H: 8`
```

**SQL**

```
  select count(*) /* its not */
  from comments
  where id_comment = ?
```

I just dont know how can I get it

Comment: Unless that number is stored with the comment there is really no concept in a database that would return a value of 8 given your scenario.

Comment: Update your question with proper table structure and headings (field names) for us to help you... This way we can't understand your table data.

Comment: Ive just updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column `id_comment` is an autoincrement id then you can count the ids that are less or equal to the one you search:

```
select count(*)
from comments
where id_comment <= (select id_comment from comments where comment = 'comment H')
```

If you want to search by `id_comment`:

```
select count(*)
from comments
where id_comment <= :id_comment
```

Or with `row_number()` window function:

```
select t.rn
from (
  select *, row_number() over (order by id_comment) rn
  from comments
) t
where t.comment = 'comment H'
```

By `id_comment`:

```
select t.rn
from (
  select *, row_number() over (order by id_comment) rn
  from comments
) t
where t.id_comment = :id_comment
```

If you choose the last query then you can add a `WHERE` clause:

```
select t.rn
from (
  select *, row_number() over (order by id_comment) rn
  from comments
  where id_comment <= :id_comment
) t
where t.id_comment = :id_comment
```

because there is no need for `id_comment`s greater than `:id_comment` to be processed.

Another solution with `COUNT()` window function:

```
select count(*) over (order by id_comment) 
from comments
where id_comment <= :id_comment 
order by id_comment desc limit 1
```

Comment: I think, that I can eventually replace `t.comment = 'comment H'` by `t.id_comment = :id_comment`, right?

Comment: I actually like yout answer, but it retrieves me error `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 106`

Comment: can you please provide me with a example link. I just cant make it work, thank you.

Comment: If you are using MySql window functions like row_number() are supported from version 8.0+. If your version is earlier then you must use one of the first 2 queries.

Comment: Otherwise all the queries are syntactically correct as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3ba720d4f94d42b0bdc7dfb87c9fc1c

Comment: it tottaly works, in the second version you posted :easy way. thank you man, you deserves a +1

Comment: Added 1 more solution with another window function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to know the number of your comment, meaning if it is the tenth comment then 10 ?
Then you should use [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
WITH MyTable AS -- you create a temp table ordered with rownumber corresponding to the line number.
(
    SELECT id_comment,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id_comment ) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM comments
) 
-- now you get this row number
SELECT RowNumber, id_comment     
FROM MyTable 
WHERE id_comment = 'H'
```

Comment: creating a temporary table doesnt increase the time respone?

Comment: It won't be more than doing the select in select. 
When creating a select in select, what sql does is storing the inside select into a table and then selecting on it.
I saw forpas answer after posting mine and I guess the execution's path will look alike. His answer is probably right too.